# jQuery Dependent Select Option

Tags: jquery, ajax, select

I trying to do 3 concatenate select options with jQuery, i have a trouble with the third select.
I dont understand why doesen't take the city value, it's appear the select arrow but not the choices.

Here my code with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//Initializing arrays with city names
var USA = [
    {display: "Washington, D.C.", value: "WashingtonDC"},
    {display: "Alaska", value: "Alaska"},
    {display: "New York", value: "New-York"},
    {display: "Florida", value: "Florida"},
    {display: "Hawaii", value: "Hawaii"},
    {display: "California", value: "California"}];

var AUSTRALIA = [
    {display: "Canberra", value: "Canberra"},
    {display: "Sydney", value: "Sydney"},
    {display: "Melbourne", value: "Melbourne"},
    {display: "Perth", value: "Perth"},
    {display: "Gold Coast ", value: "Gold-Coast"}];

var FRANCE = [
    {display: "Paris", value: "Paris"},
    {display: "Avignon", value: "Avignon"},
    {display: "Strasbourg", value: "Strasbourg"},
    {display: "Nice", value: "Nice"}];

//REGION

//Function executes on change of first select option field 
$("#country").change(function () {

    var select = $("#country option:selected").val();

    switch (select) {
        case "USA":
            city(USA);
            break;

        case "AUSTRALIA":
            city(AUSTRALIA);
            break;

        case "FRANCE":
            city(FRANCE);
            break;

        default:
            $("#city").empty();
            $("#city").append("<option>--Select--</option>");
            break;
    }
});

var ONE = [
    {display: "One", value: "One2"},
    {display: "Two", value: "Two2"}];

var TWO = [
    {display: "Three", value: "Three2"},
    {display: "Four", value: "Four2"}];

var THREE = [
    {display: "Five", value: "Five2"},
    {display: "Six", value: "Six2"}];


//Function executes on change of second select option field 
$("#city").change(function () {

    var select = $("#city option:selected").val();

    switch (select) {
        case "ONE":
            region(ONE);
            break;

        case "TWO":
            region(TWO);
            break;

        case "THREE":
            region(THREE);
            break;

        default:
            $("#region").empty();
            $("#region").append("<option>--Select--</option>");
            break;
    }
});

//Function To List out Cities in Second Select tags
function city(arr) {
    $("#city").empty();//To reset cities
    $("#city").append("<option>--Select--</option>");
    $(arr).each(function (i) {//to list cities
        $("#city").append("<option value=\"" + arr[i].value + "\">" + arr[i].display + "    </option>")
    });
}

    //Function To List out Cities in Second Select tags
function region(arr) {
    $("#region").empty();//To reset cities
    $("#region").append("<option>--Select--</option>");
    $(arr).each(function (i) {//to list cities
        $("#region").append("<option value=\"" + arr[i].value + "\">" + arr[i].display + "    </option>")
    });
}
});
```

The third select doesen't take the objects, someone know why?
Thanks

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wolfovs/4nnzy2jc/1/)

Comment: You're `city` values are `"WashingtonDC"`, etc. But in the `$('#city').change()` handler, you're looking for the values `"ONE"`, `"TWO"`, or `"THREE"`, which will never match. So you hit the default case and empty out the `region` select.

Comment: The value of city's `select` element you are getting is the name of  the city, not `"ONE" "TWO" or "THREE"`

Comment: I was going to say  var select = $("#city option:selected").val(); selects washington... but Paul said it all

Comment: Yes the problem is concatenate the values ONE TWO THREE with a city's value, there is a way?

Comment: Don't understand it if you want to make reference to the option number you can use $('option').index() instead of .val() in your second switch in jquery that way youll get if its the first,second or third city. But in that case you have to switch() case 1 case 2...etc

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem:
[image: Wrong Value Switching]

From what you can see, you're giving the wrong value to the switch statement, thus the code is not executing.

Answer (score 0):

You only have `ONE` `TWO` and `THREE` there. None of them is a matching city name.
I think you just forgot to set them to the right values instead of placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the `city`  values in order to display the regions.

You code assumes that the `city` value will be either `ONE`, `TWO` or `THREE` but it is never that.

So you always get the `default` city values applied.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see the failing select must be #region as thanks to the city function #city will be filled with city names such as Nice, Paris and so when the

```
 $('#city').change()
```

runs it will always enter the default as neither Nice nor Paris nor the other values specified in the first arrays are 'ONE','TWO' or 'THREE'.

I do not understand your intention with the regions and the cities as there are certain cities for each country but not certain regions for each city your logic is flawed here, don't worry its common but you have to think it through and pay attention to what you are doing.

To understand better add in $('#city').change() a console.log(select); run it and check your console you will see how the value of the second select will never be "ONE",'TWO' or 'THREE' and therefore will always create an empty select in base of your default declaration

Comment: The logic is not very important...it's an example. region can can be districts ot other, what interest me is to pass a set of value after city change :)

Comment: I mean change 'ONE' for 'Paris' in your second switch, run it and you'll see what I mean.(Obviously choose FRANCE in the first select and Paris in the second one)

Comment: You could use the .index() to just check which option was selected the third, the seccond etc see my comment in the main post and check http://api.jquery.com/index/